# MVC view and enumerate a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, enumerable

Using MVC3 I have this in my controller. How do I enumerate this within the view?

```
    public ActionResult NWaySwitch()
    {
        var switches = _nWaySwitch.Switches.Cast<Switch>().ToList(); 
       // var switches = _nWaySwitch.Switches;
        return View(switches);
    }
```

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

@foreach (System.Collections.ArrayList item in ViewData["switches"])
{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you made a strongly typed view here right?  If you look at the top of the view you will probably see the Model definition.  Make sure that you make this in a IEnumerable<> and you should be good to go

Comment: I'm new at this so no I'm not using a strong types.

Comment: well doing return View(switches) means that you are passing a model to a view, so it is expected that your view is strongly typed to a Switch model and more particulary in this case to a IEnumerable<Switch> model so that you can access the data in your view

Comment: I think i got it but this is returning a namespace error for Switch in the view
@foreach (var item in ViewData["getSwitches"] as IEnumerable<Switch>)

Comment: this means that the app doesn't know where to find the Switch model.  try providing the entire namespace (ie YourAppName.Models.Switch).